# Chaining method calls together

Tags: php, methods, method-chaining

For example record like this: `property3->property2->property1` is understood for me, this means that property of class, is object of another class, for example:

```
class a {
        public $property1 = "some";
}


class b {
    function __construct () {
        $this->property2 = new a();
    }           
}

$obj = new b();
echo $obj->property2->property1;
```

this understood. but I can not understood records like this: `method1()->method2()->method3()`

can you post simple example, who using these records?

Comment: Those method finish by `return $this;`.

Comment: @Ninsuo: Not always. The methods return an object, not necessarily the same object which called them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example :

```
class A {

  function fooA() {
    echo "a...";
    return $this;
  }

  function fooB() {
    echo "b...";
    return $this;
  }

  function fooC() {
   echo "c...";
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->fooA()->fooB()->fooC();
```

Or with several classes :

```
class A
{
  private $b;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->b = new B();
  }

  public function fooA()
  {
    echo "A...";
    return $this->b;
  }

}

class B
{

  public function fooB()
  {
    echo "B...";
  }

}

$a = new A();
$a->fooA()->fooB();
```

Comment: Again, you are giving an incomplete picture. It's not always that a method returns `$this` and it's magically chainable.

Answer (score 4):

It means that these functions **return** objects. For example, the following is possible (assuming $pdo is a valid PDO object):

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `table`")->fetchAll();
```

This may not always be favorable, because you:

1. Lose readabiliy.
2. Lose the ability to use the objects in between.
3. Lose the ability to check for errors, and you are counting on the methods to return what you think it is.

   In this example, you only get the resultset in the form of an `array`, but you cannot access `PDOStatement` which is returned by `PDO::query()`. In this case, it may not matter, in some cases it might.

   Also, `PDO::query()` may return a **BOOLEAN `false`** in the case of an error, which would give an unexplained "Method `fetchAll()` used on an non-object" error.

Comment: Another potential problem is if query() fails to execute and returns an error boolean rather than an object... a strong argument for thrown exceptions

Comment: @MarkBaker: Well, if we're down to specifics, you should have enabled `PDOExceptions` :)

Comment: @MarkBaker Something going wrong in the method chain is indeed why I would never use it in the first place. And this is not only about pdo, but in general. +1

Comment: @Madara - just pointing out for the benefit of future readers that may not think about that possibility, or consider using a fluent interface in other code... but when used properly a fluent interface can be very powerful and easy